# Access json elements at position[i] and change their value in a map function

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file like this

```
[
    {
        "label": "1556015903109.00",
        "value1": "1.7481",
        "value2": "1.7489",
        "value3": "1.7375",
        "value4": "2.5631"
    },
    {
        "label": "1556015954378.00",
        "value1": "1.7481",
        "value2": "1.7336",
        "value3": "1.7477",
        "value4": "2.5631"
    },
    {
        "label": "1556016004213.00",
        "value1": "1.7481",
        "value2": "1.7336",
        "value3": "1.7426",
        "value4": "2.5631"
    },
    {
        "label": "1556016034313.00",
        "value1": "1.7481",
        "value2": "1.7489",
        "value3": "1.7426",
        "value4": "2.5631"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to access all the elements under label and convert them from Unix time to datetime and update the array with the new values

I've built a map function that is supposed to access the elements and perform the necessary math wizardry to convert it to proper datetime.

```js
var json = json.map(function(a){
            var dateT= '';
              var changeUp = a.label.toString()
              for(i=0; i <changeUp.length; i++){
                  var timestamp = changeUp[i]
                  var newStamp = timestamp /1000
                  var date = new Date(newStamp * 1000);
                  var hours = date.getHours();
                  var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
                  var seconds = "0"+ date.getSeconds();
                  var formattedTime = hours +':' + minutes.substr(-2) +':' + seconds.substr(-2);
                  var dateT = date + ":" + formattedTime;
                  console.log(dateT);
                  changeUp[i] = dateT;
              }

           });
```

expected results should be

```
[
    {
        "label": "Sat April 27th 2019: 11:34:67 etc",
        "value1": "1.7481",
        "value2": "1.7489",
        "value3": "1.7375",
        "value4": "2.5631"
    },
    {
        "label": "Proper Date Time",
        "value1": "1.7481",
        "value2": "1.7336",
        "value3": "1.7477",
        "value4": "2.5631"
    },
    {
        "label": "Proper Date Time",
        "value1": "1.7481",
        "value2": "1.7336",
        "value3": "1.7426",
        "value4": "2.5631"
    },
    {
        "label": "Proper Date Time",
        "value1": "1.7481",
        "value2": "1.7489",
        "value3": "1.7426",
        "value4": "2.5631"
    }
]
```

Instead it just keeps reprinting the elements of the array or giving me NaN when I try to debug.

Comment: The content of the `json` variable is not JSON hence the name is misleading; you should be using `.forEach()` and not `.map()` (check their documentations for the _"why"_); `a.label` is already a string (`var changeUp = a.label.toString()`); `changeUp[i]` is a character of the `"label"` property

Comment: @Andreas yeah, i didn't name the variable very well.

Comment: Thanks to all. All of these solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any changeUp array:

```
var json2 = json.map(function(a){
            var dateT= '';
            var timestamp = a.label.toString()
            var newStamp = timestamp /1000
            var date = new Date(newStamp * 1000);
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
            var seconds = "0"+ date.getSeconds();
            var formattedTime = hours +':' + minutes.substr(-2) +':' + seconds.substr(-2);
            var dateT = date + ":" + formattedTime;
            a.label = dateT;
         return a;
      });

     console.log(json2);
```

Just change a.label inside map function and use return statement

Comment: I chose yours because it's the closest to my original code. Thanks

Comment: hehe ! Thanks for kindness :)  Apart from silly joke, Happy to help !!

Answer (score 2):

I see problem in your code

- Missing return value in from `map` callback,
- `label` is already a string no need to call `toString` on it again, and you're looping over each character in string so you end up getting wrong results

You can simply use `destructuring` and `map` like this

```js
let data = [{"label": "1556015903109.00","value1": "1.7481","value2": "1.7489","value3": "1.7375","value4": "2.5631"},{"label": "1556015954378.00","value1": "1.7481","value2": "1.7336","value3": "1.7477","value4": "2.5631"},{"label": "1556016004213.00","value1": "1.7481","value2": "1.7336","value3": "1.7426","value4": "2.5631"},{"label": "1556016034313.00","value1": "1.7481","value2": "1.7489","value3": "1.7426","value4": "2.5631"}]

let final = data.map(({ label, ...rest }) => {
  var newStamp = label / 1000
  var date = new Date(newStamp * 1000);
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
  var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
  var dateT = date + ":" + formattedTime;
  return {
    ...rest,
    label: dateT
  }
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the loop inside `map()`, simple modify the *label* property before returning the object:

```js
var arr = [{"label": "1556015903109.00","value1": "1.7481","value2": "1.7489","value3": "1.7375","value4": "2.5631"},{"label": "1556015954378.00","value1": "1.7481","value2": "1.7336","value3": "1.7477","value4": "2.5631"},{"label": "1556016004213.00","value1": "1.7481","value2": "1.7336","value3": "1.7426","value4": "2.5631"},{"label": "1556016034313.00","value1": "1.7481","value2": "1.7489","value3": "1.7426","value4": "2.5631"}];
var res = arr.map(i => {
  var timestamp = i.label
  var newStamp = timestamp /1000
  var date = new Date(newStamp * 1000);
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = "0"+ date.getSeconds();
  var formattedTime = hours +':' + minutes.substr(-2) +':' + seconds.substr(-2);
  var dateT = date + ":" + formattedTime;
  i.label = dateT;
  return i;
});
console.log(res);
```